# Flask HTTPBasicAuth none token inside header

Tags: python, flask, basic-authentication

I'm trying to resolve problem with Basic Authentication in flask using HTTPBasicAuth.

When I'm accessing using curl or web browser everything works well.
This are examples which works:

```
curl -u [access_token]:unused -i X GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/token
```

or

```
http://[access_token]:unused@127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/token
```

But when I'm using `Authorization: Basic [token]` or `Authorization: Basic [token]:unused` in header of request I get **500 error** from server.

Verifying access token or email and password:

```
@auth.verify_password
def verify_password(email_or_token, password):

   user = User.verify_auth_token(email_or_token)
   if not user:

      user = User.query.filter_by(email = email_or_token).first()
      if not user or not user.verify_password(password):
         return False
   g.user = user
   return True
```

User model:

```
class User(db.Model):

    def generate_auth_token(self, expiration = 600):
        s = Serializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'], expires_in = expiration)
        return s.dumps({ 'id': self.id })

    @staticmethod
    def verify_auth_token(token):
       s = Serializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
       try:
          data = s.loads(token)
       except SignatureExpired:
          return None # valid token, but expired
       except BadSignature:
          return None # invalid token
       user = User.query.get(data['id'])
       return user
```

I found that when I'm using token or email and password in header as `Basic [token/email]:[password/unused]`, `email_or_token` and `password` properties are `None`.

> Error: `TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable`

[image]

Why error occurs while using `Authorization: Basic [token/email]:[password/unused]` in header of request? What is solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must Base64-encode the the credential portion of your Authorization header. This can be done with the command line [`base64`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/base64) utility.

```
echo 'token:unused' | base64
```

From the example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), the username password combination of `Aladdin:OpenSesame` becomes:

```
Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1l
```

The reason that you don't have to worry about this with `curl` or the browser, is that they will perform the encoding automatically for you.